How to instantiate a code generated Swift `NSManagedObject` without inserting it in Swift
It is possible to instantiate a NSManagedObject without inserting it in Swift, similar to Objective C as shown in this answer. For code generated Swift NSManagedObjects  context in CodeGenedObject(context: NSManagedObjectContext) is not optional?

Why not use the same init mentioned in the answer you linked to?

Hi Joakim, I would use it if I understood how.

Create an entity description for your entity
let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: <entity name>, in: viewContext)

and then use it to create an object without a context
<entity>(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: nil)

Example for an entity Item
guard let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Item", in: viewContext) else {
    return
}
let newItem = Item(entity: entityDescription, insertInto: nil)

